# How can I add a row to my html document for every player including their stats?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

The code currently takes from a .log I have, and grabs the username of players in my lobby and returns stats (# of wins, level, etc.) of the player onto an electron HTML page in a table.
Currently, it only shows one row, with only one players' stats included in the row. I am trying to make it so that each player will show up in stacking rows.
[Picture of what the html electron window shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7T7w.png)

I also want the rows to update every time "checkforupdates" is ran but I figured I should stick to one issue at a time.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
const Hypixel = require('hypixel-api-reborn');
const hypixel = new Hypixel.Client('77684239-5a07-4ea4-bc9c-2f07db9fddb7');
const filePath = 'C:/Users/****/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/logs/blclient/minecraft/latest.log';
const keyword = 'ONLINE: ';
let lastTrimmed = '';
console.clear();
let win;


function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    win.loadFile('playerstats.html');
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

app.on('ready', async () => {

const checkForUpdates = () => {
  fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
    .then(data => {
    
      if (data.includes(keyword)) {
        const index = data.lastIndexOf(keyword);
        const line = data.substring(index);
        const parts = line.split('\n');
        const trimmed = parts[0].trim();

        if (trimmed !== lastTrimmed) {
        
          const names = trimmed.split(', ');
          names.forEach(async name => {
            const playerName = name.replace(keyword, '');
            try {
              const player = await hypixel.getPlayer(playerName);
              const winstreak = player.stats.bedwars.winstreak || '?';
              const finalKills = player.stats.bedwars.finalKills;
              const fkdr = player.stats.bedwars.finalKDRatio;
              const wins = player.stats.bedwars.wins;
              const lvl = player.stats.bedwars.level;
              win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
              document.getElementById("IGN").innerHTML = "${player}";
              document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = "${wins}";
              document.getElementById("finalKills").innerHTML = "${finalKills}";
              
          `);
        
        console.log(`(${lvl})${playerName}: ws - ${winstreak} fkdr - ${fkdr} finals - ${finalKills} wins - ${wins}`);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(`${playerName} Is Nicked`);
          }
        });
        lastTrimmed = trimmed;
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(console.error);
};

setInterval(checkForUpdates, 1000);
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Player Stats</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>IGN</th>
        <th>Wins</th>
        <th>Finals</th>
        <th>FKDR</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="IGN"></td>
        <td id="wins"></td>
        <td id="finalKills"></td>
        <td id="fkdr"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
      const playerData = window.playerData;
      document.querySelector("#IGN").textContent = playerData.player;
      document.querySelector("#wins").textContent = playerData.wins;
      document.querySelector("#final-kills").textContent = playerData.finalKills;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried looking at other forums regarding them, but every other user had more complex programs that integrated adding rows, and I couldn't figure out how to implement it into my code.
The forums i found on stackoverflow that were relevant to me only asked about a singular row.
I also thought about just adding 15 more table rows (I only need 16 rows max) but I couldn't figure out how to divert the "getElementById()" to fill out data in a different row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem, but, if you have an array of players, you could do something like:

```
<script>
 for(let i = 0; i < players.lenght; i++) {
  let table = document.getElementById("tableId")
  let newTr = document.createElement("tr")

  let td1 = document.createElement("td")
  td1.innerText = players[i].player

  let td2 = document.createElement("td")
  td2.innerText = players[i].wins

  let td3 = document.createElement("td")
  td3.innerText = players[i].finalKills

  tr.append(td1)
  tr.append(td2)
  tr.append(td3)
  table.append(tr)
 }
</script>
```

This script cycles trough an array of players and for each one of them creates a row in the table with the relative tds.
Notice that you need to give the table an id (tableId in my example) also notice that you could use thead and tbody tags.

Comment: Thanks for responding. First, I apologize for explaining my question difficultly, and I have reworded the question. 

I originally wanted to do arrays as I thought it was simpler, but I have only started learning about them so I opted to do this way instead.

Comment: unfortunately no. It still only shows one row.

Comment: did you use a player array? can you show it?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how store the player data in arrays. I only just started learning about arrays.

Comment: what does your window.playerdata contains?

Comment: I have included the picture in my edited post of what the window looks like and how the data is shown.